# wp-invoice with 2checkout

Tags: wordpress, 2checkout

Has anyone used this plug in with 2checkout? I haven't been able to find anything on the internet on steps to configure this plugin for 2checkout account. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs it does not look like 2Checkout is supported in this module but we will contact the developer to see if we can get added.

Comment: well then they shouldn't advertise that it's compatible with 2checkout. There is another plugin which is compatible with it and it's called web invoice.